# How to remove double quotes from a JSON response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to add multiple markers into a google map and i have found a way to do that [here](https://gist.github.com/parth1020/4481893).
Now I have a json array response from the server as shown below.

```
 // function to get user names and addresses
public function getUserAddresses(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::where('address', '!=', null)->select('name', 'address')->get();  //this is a laravel query

    $userData = [];

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $userData[$user->name] = $user->address;
    }
    return $userData;
}
```

This code above is what gives me the response below.

```
{
  "plumber1": "-1.2523238641713191,36.87899683074249",
  "plumber2": "-1.2192245641713191,36.87899687428849",
  "allan plumber": "-1.2192238641713191,36.87899683068849"
}
```

but for me to use this data it must be in these format as shown below in javascript.

```
[
   ["plumber1", -1.2523238641713191,36.87899683074249],
   ["plumber2", -1.2192245641713191,36.87899687428849],
   ["allan plumber", -1.2192238641713191,36.87899683068849]
];
```

Comment: `Object.entries(obj)`?

Comment: You want the result as original javascript object or json string?

Comment: as javascript object..but without the quotations marks..

Comment: @Eddie 
var locations = Object.entries(data);
i even tried that but when is console.log(locations);
it displays with the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this php code

```
$str = '{
  "plumber1": "-1.2523238641713191,36.87899683074249",
  "plumber2": "-1.2192245641713191,36.87899687428849",
  "allan plumber": "-1.2192238641713191,36.87899683068849"
}';

$array =json_decode($str);
$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $coordinates = explode(',',$value);
  $coordinate1 = (float) $coordinates[0];
  $coordinate2 = (float) $coordinates[1];
  $new_array[] = array($key,$coordinate1,$coordinate2);
}
print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => plumber1
            [1] => -1.25232386
            [2] => 36.878996830742
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => plumber2
            [1] => -1.2192245641713
            [2] => 36.878996874288
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => allan plumber
            [1] => -1.2192238641713
            [2] => 36.878996830688
        )

)
```

You can also check the demo [here](https://3v4l.org/WiHbo)
**Here is Javascript version**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var str = `{
  "plumber1": "-1.2523238641713191,36.87899683074249",
  "plumber2": "-1.2192245641713191,36.87899687428849",
  "allan plumber": "-1.2192238641713191,36.87899683068849"
}`;
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var array = [];
var counter =0;
for (var key in obj) {
  var myarr =  obj[key].split(",");
    array[counter] = [key, parseFloat(myarr[0]), parseFloat(myarr[1])];
    counter++
}
console.log(array);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Now the JSON array that i want to remove the Quotations from is a response from a get request..Meaning it is dynamic and not a string.. so from your answer. 
here -> $array =json_decode($str);

 i have to put the response direct..not a string..

Comment: and i was requesting to change the response in javascript..

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now it will give you floating numbers instead of strings

Comment: I have uploaded both versions like javascript and php. You can now enjoy it... :)

Comment: Omg!!! Thank you so much... @Zain Farooq

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_decode`

```
ini_set( 'precision', 17 );

$jsonToArray = json_decode($json, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: json_decode doesnt work for arrays..